# MySQL query action output language

Tags: mysql

I'm hoping this is a simple question. I recently installed MySQL Workbench, and thought everything was going fine, until I noticed the output of messages at the bottom. They're in a foreign language. See attached screenshot. I tried the same queries in phpMyAdmin and get similar results.

Server connection collation: utf8mb4_general_ci (I tried to change to utf8_general_ci but it won't let me)

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your **my.ini** file to the following:

```
lc-messages=en_US
```

or run the command prompt and in the mysql prompt do:

```
SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
```

Check the following [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html)

Comment: @subzeroLV: You can click the check mark on the left to accept my answer as the one that solves your problem. Happy coding and GOD bless.